# Migration error if code first approach is used for the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I my MVC 5 project I used code first approach for creating the database. However after enable migration, I am getting error

> Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations
>   to create the database and its tables, for example by running the
>   'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.

However if i delete migration folder then error is resolved but then I an unable to use migration. Please help. I am attaching screen shot for the error.

[image]

I run the command for `add-migration` and then `update-database`. That did help me. But if i change connection string and run the project again then it is not creating database until migration folder is not deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can use your database, you need to create a migration, that describes structure of your database with the `Add-Migration` command and then update your database to match you current model with the `Update-Database` command.

You might find [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621) useful.

Comment: I run the command for add-migration and then update-database. That did help me. But of i change connection string and run the project again then it is not creating database until migration folder is not deleted.

Comment: If you change your connection string, you need to run the `Update-Database` command again, because you are then working with some other database.

Comment: But if i provide application to the end-user then how can he run update-database command?

Comment: Your end user shouldn't be doing this. As part of your deliverable, you should also include a production-ready database.

Comment: Or you can use database initializers, specifically the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer. The migrations can also be invoked from code - see `DbMigrator` class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Thanks **Lukas Kabrt**. This worked for me like magic. I added `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());` and now i am able to create database at run time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If any answer on  any of your questions solved your problem, please accept it - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers I see, you have asked several questions, but haven't accepted any answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

Enable migrations just creates scripts for creating and seeding that database.  You need to run update-database from the package manager console to create the database.  The database will be created on the server referenced in your web.config connection strings

Comment: I run the command for add-migration and then update-database. That did help me. But of i change connection string and run the project again then it is not creating database until migration folder is not deleted.

Comment: You don't *have to* run update-database, it can [also be done in code](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).